# OAuth 2.0 'client credential' grant type in Cloud data fusion's source http plugin

Tags: httprequest, google-cloud-data-fusion, paylocity

I am trying to extract data from Paylocity API using cloud data fusion. I am new to this tool. The default property of the source http plugin is OAuth2. However it does not support the 'client credential' grant type. I just have the client ID and secret key with the token url with me and I do not have any Auth URL or Refresh token. Can some one help me understand how to send a GET request to Paylocity using cloud data fusion.

I tried filling in details of what I have in the http properties. However it throws an error for not filling in Auth URL or Refresh Token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the plugin does not support client credential. There is a jira open to add it (https://cdap.atlassian.net/browse/PLUGIN-773), but it has not been added yet.

Comment: Thanks for the response Albert. Is there any other way for me to extract data from an API using client credentials in Cloud data fusion?

Comment: I don't think there is anything that you could use out of the box. You could write a custom plugin (ex: a Paylocity source plugin) if you are comfortable enough (https://cdap.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/DOCS/pages/480313897/Developing+Plugins+Guide). Usually the HTTP source is a fallback when there isn't a dedicated plugin to whatever system that needs to be read from.